# Are there any images of old italic or runic inscriptions online?

Tags: book, material-culture

Wondering if there are any museums or universities or anything that have any examples of either:

- [Old Italic script](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Old_Italic_script#Block)
- [Runic script](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Runes#Unicode)

I don't think there are any books in these scripts, but it seems there are lots of inscriptions somewhere. [Here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Italic_languages) it is said of [Etruscan](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Etruscan_language):

> The most important example of these languages is Etruscan, evidenced by more than **10,000 inscriptions** and some short texts that served to conclude that this language was a non-Indo-European language and not even related to any other language except some inscriptions on the island of Lemnos in the eastern Mediterranean.

Of [runic inscriptions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Runic_inscriptions) is says there are 3 main types and in total **6k different inscriptions** in one group, and a few hundred in the others.

Wondering where you can find (a) sketches of these inscriptions in research, and (b) images of the original artifact of them. Just knowing where any of them could be located online would be helpful, then I can look for individual ones.

Here's for example one kind of image/sketch:

[image]

A better image would be like a sketch along the lines of this Cuneiform sketch:

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes. To just quote [Robert Nedoma](https://www.univie.ac.at/an/links2.html) fantastic page on this:

> [Runenprojekt Kiel](http://www.runenprojekt.uni-kiel.de/) … Database of runic inscriptions in older Fuþark
>   [Danske Runeindskrifter](http://runer.ku.dk/) … 'Runesproject Kopenhagen', gute Fotodokumentation
>   [Nationalmuseets samlinger online: Runer](http://samlinger.natmus.dk/?q=runer) … photos of mainly Danish origin
>   [Samnordisk runtextdatabas](http://www.nordiska.uu.se/forskn/samnord.htm)
>   [Sveriges Runinskrifter](https://www.raa.se/kulturarv/runor-och-runstenar/litteratur-om-runor-och-runstenar/sveriges-runinskrifter/) ... pdfs, is Swedish
>   [Runeinnskrifter fra Bryggen i Bergen](http://www.nb.no/baser/runer/) ... Catalog
>   [An English Dictionary of Runic Inscriptions of the Younger Fuþark](http://runicdictionary.nottingham.ac.uk/)
>   [Runlänkar](http://www.runforum.nordiska.uu.se/links/) 
>   [Runologi](http://hem.bredband.net/b688266/runologi.html)

Check out the links to freely available PDFs on the above page.

The Danish site has images of this quality:

> [image]

Thanks to @Tomas By:

> Here are the [Swedish ones in PDF](https://www.raa.se/kulturarv/runor-och-runstenar/digitala-sveriges-runinskrifter/digitala-sveriges-runinskrifter-publicerade-volymer/)

And curiously, [Richard Lee Morris: "Runic and Mediterranean Epigraphy", Odense University Press: Amsterdam, Philadelphia, 2012.](https://books.google.com/books?id=8LPEXoYbHZ4C&lpg=PA62), has some sketches for illustration purposes

Comment: [this](http://www.nordiska.uu.se/forskn/samnord.htm) sounds promising, but don't see much yet, seems like a scam tho too, they want me to download exe's. the [swedish link](https://www.raa.se/404-2/) 404's. The [danish site](http://runer.ku.dk/Default.aspx?page=41) has some stuff in the [search](http://runer.ku.dk/Search.aspx), like [this](http://runer.ku.dk/userfiles/image/ImgCache/3/rune01b_430.jpg) from [this](http://runer.ku.dk/VisGenstand.aspx?Titel=Haddeby-sten_3). that works, quite a few results. okay thank you! still wondering about the sketches.

Comment: Beautiful on the PDFs! [This](https://www.raa.se/runinskrifter/sri_ostergotland_b02_h02_plansch.pdf) is looking nice. Wondering now where I can get the original high quality images from what's in the PDF. The PDF is a wonderful summary.

Comment: @LancePollard Do you mean extracting the images? `pdfimages`?

Comment: No I was looking for higher quality ones, like 5000x5000px-ish.